# tabularx column text alignment color

Tags: color, tabularx

I created a tabularx table with columns specifications.

```
`\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt} %Augmente la taille des lignes du tableau
`%          \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{| >{\columncolor{DarkBlue}\color{white}}C | C | C | C | p{0.06\linewidth} |}
        \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{| C | C | C | C | p{0.06\linewidth} |}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{DarkBlue}
            \textcolor{white}{RISK CATEGORY} & 
            \textcolor{white}{RISK MEASURES / CONTROLS} &
            \textcolor{white}{FREQUENCY} & 
            \textcolor{white}{NOTES} & 
            \textcolor{white}{RISK ASS.} \\ \hline
            %\multirow{10}{*}{\begin{sideways}{\textbf {MARKET RISK}}\end{sideways}} & Monitoring of investment limits & Daily & No active breaches identified. & 25 \\ \cline{2-5}
             & Monitoring of investment limits & Daily & No active breaches identified. & \cellcolor{LightGreen} \\ \hhline{~|*4-}
             & Monitoring of Global Exposure - VaR & Daily & No breach identified and no items to be raised to the Board. & \cellcolor{LightGreen} \\ \hhline{~|*4-}
             & Monitoring of Stress testing & Monthly & No items to raise to the Board. & \cellcolor{red} \includegraphics{C:/Users/jonathanrombeau/Desktop/Report/Arrow.png} \\  \hhline{~|*4-}
            \multirow{-4}{*}{MARKET RISK} & Monitoring of Back testing & Monthly & The sub-funds Brevan Howard Dynamic Global Investment Fund had two outliers and Brevan Howard Dynamic US Investment Fund had one outlier using a VAR at 99\% confidence interval. & \cellcolor{LightGreen} \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
```

This is pretty well formatted but if you uncomment the first definition to have the colors, the title called RISK CATEGORY is no more aligned on the top of its cell.

Exemple:
 [image: Without colors]

[image: With colors]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How is the `C` column type defined? How wide is the text block?

Comment: \newcolumntype{C}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
\leavevmode\color
```

so the paragraph starts before the colour, or perhaps better if you do not want line breaking in that first column use `c` not `C` for the first column.

Comment: I do not know where to put the \leavevmode\color

Comment: `>{\columncolor{DarkBlue}\leavevmode\color{white}` instead of `>{\columncolor{DarkBlue}\color{white}`  @Eagle